# Artisan Storage:link doesnt work laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, windows, laravel-artisan

So I was trying to link my storage folder, in terminal say success but I also receive an error message`"The system cannot find the file specified."`. Before I ran storage link I also ran `npm run dev`. Any ideas?

[image: Terminal]

[image: public folder]

Comment: npm not related to your issue. Could you try to run the command in powershell ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a problem with running `php artisan storage:link` on Windows.

If you notice, there's a combination of backslashes and forward slashes in the link artisan is trying to make. Linux separates directories with `/` and Windows with `\`.

You can create the link manually with `mklink /d`. Try `mklink /d public\storage storage\app\public`

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: I would strictly move your project to `~/work` or `~/personal projects`, or anything like that, but inside WSL, not using a Windows route...

Comment: so i was edit filesystems.php in config folder and change "public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public')" to "public_path('storage') => storage_path('app\public')" still not working

Answer (score 0):

Your app appears to be missing the public folder in the storage directory. In your case laravel can’t find the folder it is supposed to link to.

[See default folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wzyd.jpg)

You can rename the company_logo folder to public and run `php artisan storage:link`

Or update your config/filesystems.php to match your folder structure

```
public_path('company_logo') => storage_path('app/company_logo'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you deleted the public folder in your archive folder before your artisan ran. Check it out and recreate it in `YOUR_PROJECT/app/storage/public`

Answer (score 0):

Your public folder under storage is missing.

Create a folder public under storage

storage/public

and then try

```
php artisan storage:link
```

After linking you should be able to see the storage folder in public. check the below screenshot.

[Storage folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnAud.png)
[Public folder after linking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jHiH.png)